# How to get the Thing Activity data, AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-iot

i am wondering if i can get access of AWS IoT **Thing Activity** like in the image :

[image]

using aws sdk like boto 3 for python?

or mybe if there are and solution so i can at least access it programmatically without have to access it from user interface.

thanks

Comment: The link to your screenshot is not accessible

Comment: @BenT sorry, i drag the image instead, thanks

Answer (score 0):

well since i already found the answer, it actually when your device subscribe from topic and the activity is logged, it actually publish the activity to topic "$aws/events/subscriptions/subscribed/{things_name}".

so you can just subscribe to that topic instead to got the activity log from/to your code.

thanks